# ReferenceError: google is not defined - Google Apps script error in Mozilla firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-apps-script, google-sites

I'm creating a Google Site with Google Apps Script "Enum Sandbox Iframe mode".

In [Google Developer Docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run), It says, to call a custom function, we need to use `google.script.run`

Sample:

***Code.gs***

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

function doSomething() {
  Logger.log('I was called!');
}
```

**index.html**

```
<script>
  google.script.run.doSomething();
</script>
```

When I run this using Google Chrome, Its working perfect. But it throws an error in Mozilla Firefox. `ReferenceError: google is not defined`.

Does anyone know the reason behind it? Any help would be appreciated.

**Update:**

Filed a bug in Google Code : https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4652&thanks=4652&ts=1419836713&

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IFRAME mode is not supported in all browsers

> This mode imposes many fewer restrictions than the other sandbox modes and runs fastest, but does not work at all in certain older browsers, including Internet Explorer 9

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/sandbox-mode

You have to switch to EMULATED or NATIVE for now. IFRAME mode is new, maybe more support will come for this with time.

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
}
```

Comment: Well, That worked perfect now. Will wait for the update from google for more browser support.