# Hosted script refuses to connect on browsers other than Chrome

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, webflow

I've uploaded my Google Apps Script to webflow and it's only working for Google Chrome browser. For other browsers I get this message (I tried with Safari and Brave):

[image: Brave visiting the webflow URL]

This is how I render my `index.html` file from the script:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index')
      .evaluate()
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}
```

I already saw this question but it isn't working with the NATIVE sandbox either: [ReferenceError: google is not defined - Google Apps script error in Mozilla firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27684512/referenceerror-google-is-not-defined-google-apps-script-error-in-mozilla-fire).

Comment: You're logged in chrome. You're not in other browsers.

Comment: Hey @TheMaster thanks for the answer. The thing is that the script doesn't show the google login form either. It only shows it if I use the Google Apps Script published URL (the long one), but not if it's hosted.

Comment: It is expected. Google doesn't want anyone framing it's page. It's a security risk. Publish using "anyone even anonymous"

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63393108

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When publishing web-apps with access: "anyone", it is needed for the end user to be logged in. Otherwise, the user is redirected to Google login page. Google's login page does not allow itself to be iframed. Since you're logged into Chrome, the web app isn't redirected to Google's login page and this error doesn't appear in Chrome.

#### Possible solutions:

- Warn users beforehand that they must login
- or Publish using access: "Anyone even anonymous"

Comment: Hey @TheMaster I only see three access options when publishing it: "Only myself", "Anyone from X organization", and "Anyone". I already have it on "Anyone" so I guess I should warn the users about that if there is no other solution

Comment: @J2RGEZ Contact your admin. They should enable anonymous access

Comment: Yeah that's the issue. It's not working on Safari but the answer is right. Thanks @TheMaster!

Comment: @J2RGEZ See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63393108